# Systemd service: Restart unit not found unless stopped first

Tags: systemd, services

I have a systemd defined service, that cannot be restarted using `systemctl` unless I first do a stop. `Systemctl` claims that the unit does not exists. This happens everytime I reboot until I execute `systemctl stop`. How can I ensure that the service can be correctly restarted without first having to call `systemctl stop`?

Example:

```
# systemctl restart merlind.service
Failed to restart merlind.service: Unit not found.
# systemctl stop merlind.service
# systemctl restart merlind.service
```

Systemd service definition:

```
[Unit]
Description=Merlin
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/merlind --config /path/to/conf --debug
ExecStop=/usr/bin/merlind --config /path/to/conf --kill
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The .service file is located at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` and symlinked at: `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/`

CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

Systemd version: 219

Comment: How did the unit file get into a `.wants` directory? That's not how systemd unit files are supposed to work. It should be in `/etc/systemd/system` and symlinked into the `.wants` directory. And better yet would be to use the tools such as `systemctl enable`.

Comment: @Patrick sorry! Actually the .service file is at /usr/lib/systemd/system/merlind.service and symlinked at:  /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants. Updated the question.

Comment: Just guessing, what happens if you use `restart merlind` instead of `restart merlind.service`

Comment: @MarkStosberg same behavior if calling with merlind instead of merlind.service unfortunately.

Comment: journalctl say anything about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I had a another service, lets call it `ServiceA`, which required `Merlin` described here, as well as some other services. However, one of the services which `ServiceA` required was missing from the system. Fixing this dependency, also fixed the problem with the Merlin service, which could then be restarted immediately at reboot, without first doing a `stop`.